# Why don't some open source libraries provide binaries?

Tags: open-source

Why don't some open source libraries provide binaries? I have noticed that some projects defer to third-parties who maintain current builds of the software, especially for Windows builds.

I ask because it seems like a barrier for adoption of a library. It's more work for the developer since he must set up his environment to build it. A developer also has to worry that he introduced bugs by building the library incorrectly.

---

**EDIT**: Some updates to address comments and answers. I've removed the examples since they're not central to the discussion. Also rephrased my question as "some open source libraries provide" rather than "open source libraries tend to provide"... didn't realize people would take offense to that.

Comment: "tend"?  Two examples is a tendency?  Do you have more data to support your claim?

Comment: Linux package managers are usually used to deploy binaries, so I don't understand that reference.

Comment: Because they are lazy pot-smoking college-educated hippies (the worst kind of hippies).

Comment: Yeah, damn hippies writing software for free that half of the world uses, screw them!

Comment: @S.Lott there are plenty more. Libvorbis/Libogg was one of the more recent ones I came across where I actually built it from source. But usually I simply search of a competing product and use that, since working out how to build the code isn't worth my time.

Comment: @CodeinChaos: I haven't built from source in years.  Fedora, Mac OS and OpenSuSE must be weird exceptions to this "tendency".  What OS are you using that's so poorly supported?  I'd like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: @S.Lott It doesn't matter which OS I'm using, it matters what OS my users are using. And if I tell my windows users to find libvorbis themselves I won't get many users.

Comment: @CodeinChaos: So, you're saying windows lacks the required pre-build binaries?  Is that where this "tendency" exists?  I'm quite confused, and I'm looking for some sense of what this question is really about.

Comment: It's a question of who is responsible for providing the binaries. On Windows the job of developer of the project in question, on Linux it's the distribution. So a windows user expect a project to supply binaries. This has a nice side for the developer too: When you support a user who has a problem you support a version of your program that you created yourself, so nobody else modified and potentially introduced bugs into it.

Comment: Why is it the responsibility of the developer?

Comment: Why is it the responsibility of the OS?

Comment: What does that mean? How can software be responsible? Where did you get that from? You stated that it's the responsibility of the developer (on Windows) or the distributor (on *ix). You must have a reason for that.

Comment: It's an observation on the different philosophies on the different OSes. A windows user expects the software creator to provide binaries he can use. On Linux a user expects the distribution to provide the binaries in their repositories.

Comment: **Commenters:** comments are meant for seeking clarification, not for extended discussion. If you have a solution, leave an answer. If your solution is already posted, please upvote it. If you'd like to discuss this question with others, please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers). See [the FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because making windows binaries is a completely different job requiring a completely different knowledge base and tool set.  People seem to have a difficult time grasping this about Linux developers, so let me turn it around.

- You've used Windows for what seems like forever.
- You only have Windows installed at home.
- You've used Linux here and there at work, but only as a user, not administrating or developing for Linux.
- You know gcc is the most commonly used compiler for Linux, but have never installed it on your own computer.
- You mainly work on the software for yourself on Windows, but don't mind making bug fixes for Linux if someone else does the work to make it compatible and distribute binaries.
- You don't want to pay for another OS and toolchain when someone else who already has is perfectly willing to make the builds.

Comment: In summary, some programmers do not have the knowledge, resources, or motivation to create binaries for other platforms.

Answer (score 11):

Cairo is a library, not an application. Postgres seems to have [Windows binaries](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows). Smaller projects often don't provide builds because they don't have the infrastructure/resources.

Comment: +1 especially "don't have the resources". Difficult to provide a tested Windows build if you don't have a license for Windows, don't have a Windows compiler (or time to experiment with cross compilers), etc.

Comment: @Steve314: Everyone has a Windows compiler - either  the open source gcc, or the free Visual Studio Express.

Comment: A library can have binaries too, namely dlls. Often I don't have the compiler (installed) nor the dependencies to build the original library. So like getting binaries, even for libraries.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Linux doesn't use `.dll` very often, so those binaries would be largely useless to some of us.  Pure source would be better.

Comment: They can be binaries, but since they're mostly aimed at developers, I can understand them not providing their own binaries.

Comment: @Steve314: Linux-Windows cross-compilers are robust real-world tools, not a far-fetched research topic. They just work.

Comment: On Linux you usually have a working c compiler installed and configured and you usually get a way with simply calling the makefile. But I'm mainly talking from the PoV of a windows user/developer. And not every developer is a c developer either.

Comment: @gbjbaanb:  Not everybody has a Windows installation, let alone a compiler.

Comment: @F'x - and that means you don't need time to experiment getting a build environment to support multiple compilers and targets right, does it? More tools always means more complexity, more experimenting getting things set up, etc. Obviously a gcc cross compiler can robustly target Windows from Linux - since MinGW gcc is robust, that's not a surprise - but it doesn't mean using it will be trivial.

Answer (score 9):

It's part of the open-source philosophy of "if you want something done, grab a shovel." Naturally, it reduces the workload on developers if the users simply compile the program themselves. No need to worry about all those architectures, OS's, etc...

But, if you're making a consumer-level product (Firefox, Paint.NET, Audacity, Keepass, etc) and you care about acquiring users, you should **always, always, *always!***  include binaries. Probably only 2% of people who stumble on your website, and are interested in your product, are going to:

- Download the appropriate SCM client
- Check out a whole copy of the source tree
- Download the IDE or compiler tools needed (easily several hundred MB for some projects)
- Download and install all of the dependencies needed (and set environmental variables)
- Run a fresh compile (easily a 10 minute process on some projects)
- Deal with any errors or problems or arise (which in small projects probably aren't documented -- "oh yeah, the latest is actually in branch-rewrite, not trunk!")
- Uninstall everything, or leave it all on your computer and re-compile for updates.

(Obviously on linux things are much saner, but most consumers still use Windows.)

It's far easier for newcomers to say "ooh, Windows version! Download. Run".

However, many open source projects are *not* consumer-level; they target programmers, who have a much higher tolerance for this sort of ordeal, and so binaries are DIY. In my experience, programmers can be just as lazy as users, though, so be warned. :)

Comment: These are exactly the types of issues that made me ask the question in the first place.

Comment: Who would distribute a project that requires an IDE to build? And people don't distribute in SCMs usually. Its more like wget, tar xfz, ./configure, make, su -c 'make install'...

Comment: Fair points, mathepic. And more modern SCM hosts (like GitHub) will let you download a zipped copy of the latest version anyway.

Comment: @mathepic: Windows developers, that's who.

Comment: @Stuart VS projects are just msbuild files. No IDE needed.

Comment: @mathepic: The Windows SDK (which you'll need to compile that msbuild) is still several hundred MB.

Comment: @Stuart P. Bentley msbuild came with my computer... in the .NET framework directory.

Answer (score 6):

Creators of applications written in a [Write Once Compile Anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_compile_anywhere) environment (C, C++, etc) benefit from pushing the compilation step down to distributors (apt, rpm, yum, etc) that create and package binaries for popular architectures. This achieves a maximally portable application with less effort on the part of the creators and allows them to spend more time focusing on their core competency (developing the application, not compiling and hosting it for multiple architectures). Some WOCA application creators are willing to pay the extra cost in special cases like Windows because – well – no one else will, the users expect it, and they don't want to give up the market.

On the other hand, applications written in a [Write Once Run Anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) environment (Java) or for a specific target architecture (OS X applications, for instance) are able to provide a single binary and often do so since they only have to pay the compilation cost once.

Finally, their users are typically comfortable either building from source or using their OS package manager, so this model provides better usability as well. Users know where to get binaries (their package manager), have a consistent installation and package management lifecycle experience, and know where to acquire the source should they need it.

Comment: One problem with write-once-run-anywhere is that the virtual machine is a program in its own right, from the point of view of the O/S. For example, most Windows firewalls allow you to grant/deny access to networks on an app-by-app basis. But most of them can't tell one Java app from another - they grant/deny access to the JVM, but if you have one Java app that acts as an internet server (Azureus, perhaps) then the firewall will not block any unknown rogue Java application from acting as a server. If there's a Java-specific solution, I'm an example of a Java user who doesn't know about it.

Comment: @Steve I'm not disagreeing with you per se but I don't really see how the pros/cons of WOCA or WORA are relevant to this question.

Comment: tangential, true, but in a question that's already a bit of a Linux vs. Windows etc religious war, maybe one of the lesser crimes. BTW - I did +1 your answer as useful.

Comment: Yay religious war! I'll get the tar, you get the feathers?

Answer (score 5):

Why would I want to chew up bandwidth providing you with a build (which can obviously be very large) rather than you building the source which I'm providing you with anyway? Not to mention that building a project on your own machine will *always* yield better results as it's compiled specifically for your platform..

Comment: +1 - but I doubt "always" (depends on what platform you're using), and those benefits can come at some cost to the user - needing a compiler, needing to know how to use it, needing to know how to build that specific project, needing to spend time investigating and reporting the wierd bugs that turn up only on your particular platform, etc.

Comment: @steve314: +1, all true points :)

Comment: A few binary files are usually not that big. And the time cost to the user is usually really large. Finding all dependencies and figuring out how to build that specific project takes quite a lot of time. Even if your user happens to be a programmer. If the user is no programmer he can pretty much forget about your product. And I think the performance argument is way overrated. Usually you don't need that last percent of performance, and if you do then you can still figure out how to build from source.

Comment: @codeinchaos: That's entirely relative to the project (size). A build could be encompass a single binary, or several hundreds of MBs (if not more) in binaries and non-compiled assets (think games). Of course, sometimes nailing down dependencies can be a bit of a pain, but that's up to the author of the package to either provide a list, or a build-time mechanism of downloading/building dependencies (FreeBSD's ports collection is *great* for that). Projects directed at non-programmers will almost always have a binary/installer list maintained somewhere.

Comment: Thing is, many open source projects aren't "products" in the usual sense. Since open source is about allowing contributions in various forms, having other people provide binaries that know how to do it and have the time to maintain them seems like a good idea.

Comment: @phaylon: Agreed, it seems like a good idea, but the bandwidth that would be required in order to build and test binaries on `n` platforms is beyond the resource capacity of most OS projects.

Comment: @Demian: That's what I mean. For that reason it makes sense to have stuff built by people that are actually using those platforms like mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Demian - I know of at least one project where a Windows binary is contributed by a user, typically some time after a new release - http://www.complang.org/ragel/ - though there hasn't been a new release in a couple of years.

Comment: In response to this answer: I don't understand the performance claim. Performance optimizations at compile time tailored for my build machine are not useful... I want optimizations for my target platform, which I get through compiler options, not the actual machine I am using to run the compiler. So there's no performance benefit for me to compile the libraries myself over the library's authors.

Comment: @emddudley: The assumption is made that you're building the project on the machine that you'll be using it with.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two reasons.

First, you have multiple operating systems running on multiple types of hardware; the number of binary targets you would have to build gets unmanagable.  There are three versions of Windows still commonly in use (XP, Vista, 7) running on 32-bit or 64-bit hardware; that's 6 binary targets right there.  The situation's worse on the Linux side, with a much larger variety of distros running on God knows what hardware (x86, PPC, MIPS, SPARC, PA-RISC, etc.).  Are you going to build for *every* possible combination?  Do you even have the equipment and/or software to do so?  If there's someone out there still running (God help us) NT on a PII, are you going to build a binary for them?

Second, shipping source means that users can optimize the build for their particular environment; they can turn on whatever optimizations they need, or tweak the source itself if necessary.

Comment: so I guess the answer is to use something like Sourceforge's build servers. Checkin, let them build you lots of binaries. Such as http://en.opensuse.org/Build_Service

Comment: Since those programs usually don't use any special Vista/Win7 features and 32 bit programs run on 64 bit OSes you can almost always get away with a single 32 bit WinXP binary for all windows users.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - +1 - some projects provide both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries, but providing more variations than that is rare. A valid point, though.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - *an* answer, certainly, but probably not *the* answer.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the value of an open-source project, be it an application, system, module or library, is that it can be studied and/or modified as needed. Distributing the source is intrinsic to the publishing model.

Distributing a binary runs the risk that it has been modified in some fashion for nefarious purposes. Compiling the project from source attempts to mitigate that risk.

Comment: For applications >90% of the users will never even look at the source. And the risk of manipulation is something most downloaders of binaries are willing to take. They can't (and even if they could they'd be too lazy) to verify that a sourcecode doesn't contain malicious code.

Comment: True, but the OP asked why open-source projects aren't typically distributed as binaries, not "as a user, why do I have to compile all this stuff?" ;-)

Comment: But you're arguments are on why it's better for the user that he gets the source and not the binaries.

Comment: Funny, I don't see the word 'user' in either my answer or the original question. Perhaps I'm reading my own answer incorrectly?

Comment: Downloading a modified binary is a risk to the user. And the user mitigates the risk for himself. The developer knows his binary is clean because he built it himself(unless the server got hacked, but then he has a bigger problem anyways). And the studying/modifying part is just as possible if you distribute a binary in addition to the source. So neither of your arguments shows an advantage for the creator of the product if he doesn't provide a binary. So I don't see anything it your answer giving a reason for not providing binaries.

Comment: Interesting that you seem hell-bent on misinterpreting my comments as I did not attempt to provide "a reason for not providing binaries." I simply provided an explanation for why open-source projects are typically distributed as source code. Thanks for playing but this is my last comment on this.

Comment: Open source projects offer their source by definition. So I understand the OP's question as "Why don't they offer binaries in addition to the source?" and not as "Why don't they offer binaries instead of the source?"

Comment: Source code can be tampered with (kinda what "Open Source" is for), and in the real world, few users do thorough source code audits. When programmers added "back door" security holes, for example, they were added to the source, not the binary. Ken Thompsons classic paper "reflections on trusting trust" also has some interesting points to make about the (in)validity of the built-from-source = safe myth. For getting clean sources, solutions are typically the same as for clean binaries - check the MD5 hash or whatever. Oh - and don't let Ken Thompson anywhere near your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This can have several reasons. Many (if not most) open source projects start on Linux. So the initial project is done for this system and the packaging is done by team members.

Creating a Windows installer is extra work which requires knowledge that the Linux developers may not have. So if somebody from outside the core team takes on this work, he is often mentioned specially.

The same may be true for other systems like OS X or even specific Linux distributions. It all depends who has the knowledge and the time to do the extra work.

Comment: A windows installer is rarely requires. A zip file with the binaries is fine too. But of course you're right that many linux based devs won't care much about a windows version of their program.

Comment: A zip file can be a great handicap in the Windows world. 'I have downloaded this file. Now when I click it windows tells me its "unknown file format"' is a quite common problem in help forums.

Comment: I've published all my stuff as .zip files. I think the only complaint I got in this context was by some guy who managed to copy the exe file to his desktop instead of creating a link. But in any case the difficulty of building from source is much higher than the difficulty of unzipping something.

Comment: Depends in part on your user base. If you publish a library that's only used by programmers you won't have problems with zip files. Zip is easy enough so every audience with basic knowledge gets it done. Though i have seen the zip question often enough...

Comment: Keep in mind that in XP+, zip files are handled natively by the OS, and enough double clicking will open the file in an extracted folder.